# How to process only one column and convert unix time in text file in BASH

Tags: bash, sed, awk, xargs

I have a text file with table like

```
367612510.243586 717.860170
367612512.493918 722.249134
367668441.429983 692.407935
367668479.810461 692.407935
367668482.618858 727.953771
367668515.150386 727.953771
```

where the first column is UNIX time, and the second is some value. I want to display this list with human readable date and time in BASH. How to do it?

It is possible to do it with additional script file and xargs, but I'm looking for way to do it in one line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
awk '{print strftime("%c",$1)}' input.txt
```

another approach using a while-loop in bash

```
while read d _; do date -d @$d; done < input.txt
```

update:

bash solution to print the second field as well

```
while read f1 f2; do echo $(date -d @$f1) $f2; done < input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! My command is `awk '{print strftime("%c",$1), $2}' input.txt`.

Comment: Note: the first variant works only in gawk, but not in mawk which is default in Debian.

Comment: yes, strftime() is gawk-specific. Get gawk. Don't do the while loop.